# How do I unset the default home screen programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity which acts like a home screen. My question is how can I programmatically ask the user which home screen wants to be the default? I don't want to set my home screen as the default, but to show to the user the dialog to choose the home screen he wants.

Answer (score 4):

> My answer is how can I programmatically ask the user which home screen wants to be the default?

The only way to do that is to trigger the home screen to appear, by starting an `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME` activity. If there is a choice to be made, between your home screen, the device default home screen, and others, the user will get a chooser and will be able to choose which home screen to display. They will also get the "make this the default for this action" checkbox. However, this also has the effect of taking the user to their chosen home screen, and they do not have to set a default.

My recommendation would be for you to leave this alone. They will see this chooser the next time they press the HOME button, anyway, and they will then expect to go to their chosen home screen.

Comment: Thank you and I know what you mean. I want the user have the choice to change the default home screen, and asked for the new default one, for example when he press a button in my app. I want to clear the default screen. When the user selects my home screen as default, I can clear it with the packagemanager and clearPackagePreferredActivities(), but when the default home screen is another, i can't.

Comment: @androidGR: "for example when he press a button in my app. I want to clear the default screen" -- that is not possible. "but when the default home screen is another, i can't" -- correct.